# When is dual norm equal to norm of the adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Suppose $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$, and $\|\cdot\|_D$ is the dual of the norm $\|\cdot\|$. When is the following true?

$$\|A\|_D=\|A^*\|$$

Two examples that come to mind are row-sum/column sum norms for matrix $A$ and operator norm/induced trace norm for positive linear map $T$ (Bhatia [book](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/%7Elessa/tesis/Positive%20Definite%20Matrices.pdf), Equation 2.37)

**Edit** relevant section from Horn/Johnson "Matrix Analysis", page 357:

[image]

Comment: Some questions: (1) the text is focussing on matrices, so what is the definition of the adjoint of a matrix: is it conjugate-transpose, or does it depend on the norm somehow? (2) What is your definition of a "dual" of a norm - a norm is not a linear function and so duals in the usual sense do not apply.

Comment: I think dual norm has a standard definition, Boyd's convex optimization book has it in appendix

Comment: Also adjoint is defined through inner product, Bhatia book has defn